# How can I display json data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, json

My JSON data looks like this:

```
safarisDetails: {
    loading: false,
    safaridetails: {
      safari: [
        {
          id: 1,
          safari_name: '3 DAYS GORILLA TREKKING TRIP',
          days: 3,
          days_category: '<4',
          budget: '900',
          title: '3 DAYS GORILLA TREKKING TOUR',
          text: 'Test.',
          travelertype: '',
          date_created: '2021-10-08T15:22:31.733347Z'
        }
      ],
      highlight: [
        [
          {
            id: 1,
            highlight: 'See the famous mountain gorillas',
            safaris: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            highlight: 'Get to know the Batwa community',
            safaris: 1
          }
        ]
      ]
```

I want to render objects in my component such as the safari_name and loop trough the highlights. However, when I use {safarisdetails.safari.safari_name} i get an error message stating: 'safari_name' is not defined.

Comment: safari is an array. You will need to iterate through the elements or chose a single element before accessing its properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems based on the same you provided...

- `safarisdetails` is repeated twice in the JSON, but not in your check
- `safari` is an array in the JSON, but accessed like an object in your check

For example, to get the first name, you'd write something like:
`safarisdetails.safarisdetails.safari[0].safari_name`

Also, is this JSON even valid? Maybe you posted a partial snippet, but the JSON has to have `{}` around the whole thing.